# Are "Is there an example for game where you can..." questions are on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I develop games in my free time for fun. But I find it quite demotivating when I find that the idea I thought to be original already implemented years and decades ago. Even if I cannot find an example by searching the web.

So it's not worth making a yet another one, because it would be the same old boring thing.

So is it on-topic to ask whether a game exist that implements a particular idea or combinations of ideas?

Examples:

Is there an FPS game where you can build a base to defend your team? 
Yes there is: Tremulous for example.

Is there a game where you have 6 degrees and freedom and play in a closed level? Yes there is: Descent.

Of course these are well known, I would ask about different combinations I couldn't find examples for.

Comment: The chaps over at the game dev stack exchange might be able to help, but please check their acceptable questions before asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, such questions are not on-topic. This in effect is asking for game(s) that fit certain criteria, which is explicitly forbidden in our help:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> Please note, however, that site policies prohibit questions of the following types:
>
> ...
>
> - Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game)

Whether you ask for just one example or want a fuller list doesn't matter, because the end result will be creating such a catalog in the answers.